# Custom GMT format date pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I'm using angular default date pipe for formatting my date, using this code.

`{{'27-04-2021 08:30:00' | utcDate | date: 'EE, d MMMM OOOO'}}`

The result is `Tue, 27 April GMT+05:30`

I have to show the result as `Tue, 27 April GMT+5:30`

I have to format the GMT format from `XX:XX to X:XX`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this method in your component.

```
  replaceZone = (val: string | null): string => {
    if (val == null) {
      return '';
    }
    return val.replace(/0(\d:\d{2})$/, '$1');
  }
```

Then call like this.

```
{{replaceZone('27-04-2021 08:30:00' | utcDate | date: 'EE, d MMMM OOOO')}}
```

Comment: its showing the same date format `Tue, 27 April GMT+05:30`.

Comment: Try one 0 less ``  date: 'EE, d MMMM OOO' `` for the shorthand writing (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) . If this doesn´t fit (because of the :30 addon), then i fear you will have to write your own formater. Or talk to the business responsibles and ask them if a non standard writing style is worth the effort of creating such a formater.
As i like to say "Follow the standards or be ready to pay at least twice. Once for creating a special case, and once for maintenance")

Comment: Hi @JanRecker Its showing only hours. that's `Tue, 27 April GMT+5`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try again.

Comment: define `replaceZone` method inside custom pipe rather than call directly inside `{{ }}` interpolation, because, every change detection cycle interpolation calls replaceZone method and gives performance issue of app